# Original price formula after discount

Tags: percentages, percentile

I need a short formula to calculate the original price.
e.g A fridge cost £ 200 after 50% reduction. Calculate the original price

Answer (score 0):

Original Price = O.P

Sale Price = S.P

(100 - 27) = 73%

As we know

**Formula**

S.P/O.P * 100 = obtained percentage

So its

125/O.P * 100 = 73

**Solution**

O.P = 125 * 100 / 73

**Answer**

171.23